# Excel Services in SharePoint Online

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have a working code using Excel Services published on on-premises SharePoint:

```
var _service = new ExcelService { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
Status[] _status;
var _sessionId = _service.OpenWorkbookForEditing("http://<sharepoint url>/<list>/<file>.xlsx", "en-US", "en-US", out _status);
```

`ExcelService` is a valid web reference pointing to `http://<sharepoint url>/_vti_bin/excelservice.asmx`

However, the same code doesn't work when using the Excel Services on SharePoint Online.

I am able to get the API version:

```
_service.GetApiVersion(out _status);
```

> Excel Web Services (16.0)

But opening a workbook throws a `SoapException`:

> We couldn't find the file you wanted.

I tried passing the credentials:

```
var _pass = new SecureString();
foreach (char _c in "<SP Online password>".ToCharArray()) { _pass.AppendChar(_c); }
var _cred = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("<SP Online login>", _pass);
var _service = new ExcelService { Credentials = _cred };
```

And the credentials seem to be valid, i.e. this code works:

```
// login test
using (ClientContext _sp = new ClientContext("<SP Online url>") { Credentials = _cred })
{
    var _web = _sp.Web;
    _sp.Load(_web);
    _sp.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(_web.Title);
}
```

What am I missing?

- It seems it's an authentication issue but it's hard to tell since the error message is pretty opaque. How can I find out more details about the error?
- Are Excel Services exposed only for specific licences?

Note, I am able to use Excel REST API but that doesn't work in my scenario (heavy editing).

Comment: It sounds to me like you're getting to Excel Services just fine, but the Excel Services instance is having trouble getting to your file.  Have you verified that your Excel Services instance has permissions to wherever you're keeping the file?  (It looks like you're storing it in a SharePoint List somewhere.)

Comment: We're you able to find a solution to this?